# I just noticed I Installed 64-bit system by mistake

Tags: 64-bit, system-installation, 32-bit

I have a Gateway M-6804m Notebook with 3GB of RAM
https://support.gateway.com/s/Mobile/2007/Tempest/1014839R/1014839Rsp2.shtml

I installed ubuntu with the windows installer about 2 weeks ago, but I didn't noticed until now, that it installed a 64-bit system instead of 32-bit system, now I'm searching on many websites about the 64-bit system requirements(including here), but what I'm not sure is if it's going to run faster if I install the 32-bit system because I've read that with a 64-bit system will work harder than a 32-bit OS.
I've noticed that sometimes when I play videos on YouTube in low quality with an html5 player it runs slightly slow than my 32-bit Windows 7.
I might try the 32-bit system, but I want to hear something from you before I do anything.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If your architecture is 64-bit, a 64-bit system should be faster and more efficient. In any case this question is well beyond Ubuntu, I suggest you put it up at [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 64-bit software *can* be more efficient, but it varies wildly.  It's often anything but if you're running 32-bit apps in a 64-bit environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have [a 64bit CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/30786/intel-core2-duo-processor-t5250-2m-cache-1_50-ghz-667-mhz-fsb).

Comment: A 64-bit system also requires at least 4 GB of RAM, isn't that true? I only have 3 GB of RAM. Thanks for answering

Comment: No it doesn't require 4GB of RAM.

Comment: I run full 64 bit Ubuntu but not Unity on a 2006 laptop with 1.5GB of RAM. Intel video chip a bit limited to run Unity. But you may have issues if Windows is 32bit and wubi is 64 bit. Since 12.04 is last supported wubi you may be better doing a full partitioned install, so eveything is native.

Comment: @1544C the main differences between 64 and 32 bit is the amount of RAM supported natively and the size of the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that 64-bit Ubuntu is now the default version. We should just let 32-bit versions go.

64-bit Ubuntu works perfectly fine.